# Finding the second derivative; What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Original Question:

$xy+y-x=1$

Find the second derivative;

$d^2y\over{dx^2}$$(xy+y-x=1)$

We are allowed to use either notation as far as I know: ${dy\over{dx}}$ or ${y'}$. Because ${dy\over{dx}}=y'$ according to my Math 1000 prof.

$(xy)'+y'-x'-1'=0'$

$(y+xy')+y'-1=0$

$y'(x+1)-1+y=0$

$y'(x+1)=1-y$

$y'={1-y\over{x+1}}$

Now we're supposed to find $y''$ but, that's where I mess things up. Quotient rule:

$y''={{(1-y)'(x+1)-(1-y)(x+1)'}\over[(x+1)]^2}$

$y''={{(-y')(x+1)-(1-y)(1)}\over[(x+1)]^2}$

$y''={{-({{1-y}\over{x+1}}){\cdot}(x+1)-(1-y)}\over{(x+1)^2}}$

$y''={{-(1-y)-(1-y)}\over{(x+1)^2}}={-2(1-y)\over{(x+1)^2}}={2(y-1)\over{(x+1)^2}}$

But, The answer is supposed to be ${y''={{y-1}\over{(x+1)^2}}}$

Why am I getting a 2? That's all I want to know.

Also, I took out the unnecessary equal signs, my prof wants us to have those cause he's basically insane but, it's confusing everyone so I'm taking them out.

The improper method! According to my prof:

$(xy)'+y'-x'-1'=0'$

$(y+xy')+y'-1=0$

$y'+(xy')'+y''=0$

$y'+(y'+xy'')+y''=0$

$y''(x+1)=-2y'$

${y''={{-2y'}\over{x+1}}}$

Plugin $y'$ and it's the same answer i'm getting. Supposedly the wrong one everywhere I've looked.

Comment: To show that's what the first derivative is equal to. Want to include all steps including how the problem is executed. Most people on these forums complain about not enough steps given. Figured I'd be extra thorough.

Comment: I think that's a little bit much, and I don't think that membership entitles anyone to make demands of any other member.

Comment: @Hawk And I've been using the site for nearly two years and I see no issue with the OP's question, his approach, or his justificiations. However, I have never until today encountered such a brazen demand, particularly of a new user.

Comment: If that be the case, I return my remarks and demands and apologise to OP.

Comment: Note, I don't think it's causing any error, but it's incorrect to say $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dxy}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dx}+\cdots$$ as you have in your third line. I know what you're trying to say, but you're adding in a factor of $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Remember, in implicit differentiation, we're differentiating both sides of the equation. The equation corresponding to your third line would be $$y=xy+y-x-1,$$ which is not what we're given.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you have to do, but I don't see any formal mistake in what you wrote. I agree with Arkamis that there is a concept error, but it is immaterial as far as the result is concerned.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to fid the second derivative of y with respect to x, why not expressing y as a function of x?

Comment: The 3rd line as you've shown $y=xy+y-x-1$ is never mentioned. It is only mentioned as $xy+y-x-1=0$

Comment: @Gixbit, have you ever considered if the answer could have a typo.

Comment: @satishramanathan Yes, And honestly, I've done this problem on paper close to 20-30 times, Lost count. Me and this problem have a love-hate relationship.

Comment: It if funny, Have fun!!!

Comment: @Francisco $f(x) = y$ Therefore, $f'(x) = y'$ That is why I do not express y as a function of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

I will tell you why you have been confused.  I looked at your Wolfram Answer and you have wrongly specified such as

derivative of $\frac{(1-y)}{(1+x)}$ .  Wolfram Alpha thinks that it is the partial derivative of this and treats y as a constant and merely calculates $(1-y).\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1+x)}$ and this ofcourse will be

${(1-y)}\frac{-1}{(1+x)^{2}}$ and eventually spits out $\frac{(y-1)}{(1+x)^{2}}$ and you think you have been wrong.

Now specify in wolfrom alpha the following way:

$\frac{d}{dx} ((1+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+(y-1))$  This is valid because y'(1+x) + y-1 =0, Now you have to find y''

and see what solution you get.  You will be right on track.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%28%281%2Bx%29dy%2Fdx%2B%28y-1%29%29

Good luck

Comment: @gixbit, see the solution that I have posted.  Satish

Comment: It clearly doesn't understand the quotient rule. I can already see from what you've shown me that it's not that sophisticated afterall.

Comment: The best way to check work: $2x^3-y^2-8=0$--->

$6x^2-2yy'=0$--->

$y'={{3x^2}\over{y}}$

and

$h=\sqrt[3]{{8+k^2}\over{2}}$--->

Then--->
$y-k=y'(x-h)$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/trqatryhln

Answer (score 2):

Edit: After your equation changes, your work is correct and the "supposed" answer is wrong.

Comment: Because it's wrong. The original question is: 

$xy+y-x=1$

re-written as:

$xy+y-x-1=0$

Which ends up being:

$y+xy'+y'-1=0$

Comment: @Gixbit do you know that the derivative of a constant is 0? This is always true.

Comment: @qwr, Gixbit is right and I am suspecting the answer has a typo.  If you carefully evaluate, the OP is correct because the -1 is from  differentiating -x

Comment: @satishramanathan Gixbit has edited his original equation literally  1 minute ago, now I have to go through and make changes.

Comment: @qwr, if you further differentiate it, the OP's answer is rightfully right.

Comment: I don't see the change affecting your answer

Comment: I reversed my downvote and added additional points to you, now you realized it. I am sorry.

Comment: $x$ is not a constant. $e$ is a constant or $5$ or $pi$. $c' = 0$. Except in cases like ${{{{4}\over{3}}{\pi}r^3}}$

Comment: Also, [Wolfram's Answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%281-y%29%2F%28x%2B1%29)

Which says I AM wrong. But, Am I really wrong? I like to believe I'm good at math but, when I check my answers and everything says I'm wrong, I get irritated.

Comment: @Gixbit, Please see the clarification at the answer below